# plot entire row on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have an entire row from the matrix. And I try to do bar plot.I try to find any examples but I couldn't so, can somebody help me?

```
In [9]:Atot1
Out[9]: 
     T    G    C   -    A    C    T   -    A    G    T   -    A    G    C   
SAMPLE                                                                          
1       97  457  178  75  718  217  193  69  184  198  777  65  100  143  477   

     -   A   T   G   C  
SAMPLE                      
1       54  63  43  55  47
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the row:

```
row = df.iloc[0]
```

Plot the row (a `pandas.Series`):

```
row.plot(kind='bar')
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'columns': ['T', 'G', 'C', '-', 'A', 'C', 'T', '-', 'A', 'G', 'T', 
                 '-', 'A', 'G', 'C', '-', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'C'],
     'data': [[97, 457, 178, 75, 718, 217, 193, 69, 184, 198,
               777, 65, 100, 143, 477, 54, 63, 43, 55, 47]],
     'index': [1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'], columns=d['columns'], index=d['index'])
df.columns.names = ['SAMPLE']

row = df.iloc[0]
row.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: If you want to plot two rows, so that on the x axis you have the category and then you have two bars for each category, how do you avoid them being stacked?

Comment: It works, but how do you add a label for the row into the legend? How do you plot multiple rows?

Comment: The proposed method seems not to be working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943842/plotting-entire-row-of-a-dataframe