# Plot a row in Panda/Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, row

I know it can look basic but I didnt find anything about it...

In panda I have a dataframe with one row only. the index is a date and the columns are the date, the data are regular figures...

I want to plot all the row... any idea?

```
            2017-03-23  2017-03-22  2017-03-21  2017-03-20  2017-03-17  2017-03-16  
maturity                                                                       
2020-04-30       41       -20         15.3         21.21       -0.86        61.2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plot entire row on pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105817/plot-entire-row-on-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select a row by it index and then plot:

```
row = df.iloc[0]
row.plot()
```

[image]