# Multiple lineplots with a dependency variable

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

One dataframe contains the percentage change of several nerve amplitudes at the corresponding measurement points and a second their respective diameters.

```
>>> amp.head()
   Timepoint 1  Timepoint 2  Timepoint 3  Timepoint 4  Timepoint 5  Timepoint 6
0     1.277778     0.944444     0.444444          0.0          0.0          0.0
1     0.941176     0.705882     0.352941          0.0          0.0          0.0
2     0.818182     0.490909     0.309091          0.0          0.0          0.0
3     1.000000     0.658537     0.414634          0.0          0.0          0.0
4     0.588235     0.455882     0.323529          0.0          0.0          0.0

>>> dia.head()
0    1.3
1    1.1
2    1.2
3    1.5
4    1.6
```

I would like to plot the amplitudes in relation to their diameter, as `hue='insert column here'` does in many Seaborn plots.

```py
def plot_rows(df, color="xkcd:red"):
    # Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105817/plot-entire-row-on-pandas

    number = df.shape[0]
    rows = range(number)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.show()
```

Although this function does plot the amplitudes row by row, it doesn't show their diameter. Is it possible to do so any other way?

I thought about combining both datasets, sort them according to the diameter, divide the diameter in let's say 3 groups and then plot them all on the same graph with different colors, but I just can't figure out how.

Something like this was my first take

```py
new_df = pd.concat([amp, dia], axis=1)
# sort the values into categories and exclude "Diameter [mm]" from the plot
small = new_df[(new_df["Diameter [mm]"] < max(new_df["Diameter [mm]"]) / 2)][:-1]
plot_rows(small[[small.columns.values]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. I had to do some learning to come up with this answer. Perhaps somebody else can add to this post, maybe there is an easier or better solution!

I put your subset data into a CSV and placed it to a dataframe (amp) and series (dia). Your data are much easier to plot if you simply take the transpose of amp.

```
>>> amp.T
>>>
                   0           1           2           3           4
Timepoint 1 1.277778    0.941176    0.818182    1.000000    0.588235
Timepoint 2 0.944444    0.705882    0.490909    0.658537    0.455882
Timepoint 3 0.444444    0.352941    0.309091    0.414634    0.323529
Timepoint 4 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Timepoint 5 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
Timepoint 6 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

I was able to get an answer together and apply it to your dataset using the following posts/resources.
[Line collection tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html)
[Excellent post by @ahwillia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208700/matplotlib-plot-lines-with-colors-through-colormap)

Basically you use the [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) class to apply a colormap to the lines with [mpl.cm.ScalarMappable.set_array](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.set_array) and then plot them at the same time by adding the collection to the axis. This also facilitates use of a colorbar. Reviewing these documentation may help you understand the implementation better and apply it more broadly to datasets. Here is an implementation for your data.

[image]

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import ticker

#read CSV and define diameter
amp = pd.read_csv('stack_overflow.csv')
dia = pd.Series([1.3, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.6])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

#xs are a len(timepoints) X len(timepoints) matrix one row of xs for each line
#ys are a len(timepoints) X len(timepoints) matrix one row of ys for each line
xs = [np.arange(len(amp.columns))] * len(amp.columns)
ys = amp.values

#segments is an array of x/y pairs, such as multiple of the following
# [[0.  1.277778]
 # [1.  0.944444]
 # [2.  0.444444]
 # [3.  0.      ]
 # [4.  0.      ]
 # [5.  0.      ]]
segments = [np.column_stack([x, y]) for x,y in zip(xs, ys)]
#create LineCollection object and pass **kwargs
lines = LineCollection(segments, cmap = 'viridis', linewidth=3.5)

#set_array is a cmap function that takes the dia values and normalizes them
#then maps to the colormap provided to lines
lines.set_array(dia)

#plot lines and scale axis
ax.add_collection(lines)
ax.autoscale()

#add colorbar
ax_cb = fig.colorbar(lines)

#styling
hide_spines = [ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
tic_params  = ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14, bottom=True, left=False)
x_ticks     = ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(amp.columns)))
tick_labels = ax.set_xticklabels(amp.columns)
y_label     =  ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Alternatively, if you just want to plot the lines and color them, it's quite simple to do with pandas plotting on amp.T with a seaborn colormap. Though I couldn't find a way to show the colorbar with this implementation

[image]

```
amp.T.plot(color=sns.color_palette("Set2", 8), figsize=(12,8), linewidth=3.5)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(edgecolor='w', fontsize=14)
hide_spines = [ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
tic_params  = ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14, bottom=True, left=False)
x_ticks     = ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(amp.columns)))
tick_labels = ax.set_xticklabels(amp.columns)
y_label     =  ax.set_ylabel('Amplitude', fontsize=14)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this very well written answer! The first solution works and looks as requested, but when a `df` with 128 amplitudes is passed to it, only 6 of them are displayed. Is it possible to show all of them as in your second solution?
Your second solution does indeed show all the amplitudes, but I can't see the dependence to the diameter parameter. How would you include that parameter without having them just all start from the diameter as "Timepoint 0" after concatenating `amp` and `dia`?

Comment: Do you have more timepoints or more nerves? You can probably solve the problem by making sure 'xs' and 'ys' select the correct x and y data for your intended plots. Play with them a bit and see if you can get the correct x and y. Make sure dia is also the appropriate length equal to number of nerves. The second solution will not be able to show dependence on diameter by color.

Comment: Indeed, by changing it to `xs = [np.arange(len(amp.columns))] * amp.shape[0]` all amplitudes were plotted. Thank you very much and have a great day!