# Plotting entire row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I followed the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32105953/859227) to plot a dataframe based on the row number. The data frame looks like:

```
print(df)

      Metric Value Metric Value Metric Value Metric Value

0             3            3            7            7
1             1            1            1            1
2             0            0            0            0
3             1            1            1            1
4           512          512          512          512
5          0.04         0.04         0.04         0.04
```

However, the following code seems to be wrong

```
    row = df.iloc[4]
    row.plot(kind='bar')  # TypeError: no numeric data to plot
    plt.show()
```

The `print(row)` shows

```
Metric Value    512
Metric Value    512
Metric Value    512
Metric Value    512
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

How can I fix that? I expect to see 4 bars and the y-axis for all of them is 512.

UPDATE:

The full error is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_512/3965164144.py in <module>
     58         row = df.iloc[4]
     59         print(row)
---> 60         row.plot(kind='bar')
     61         plt.tight_layout()
     62         plt.show()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    970                     data.columns = label_name
    971 
--> 972         return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    973 
    974     __call__.__doc__ = __doc__
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     69             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     70     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 71     plot_obj.generate()
     72     plot_obj.draw()
     73     return plot_obj.result
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in generate(self)
    284     def generate(self):
    285         self._args_adjust()
--> 286         self._compute_plot_data()
    287         self._setup_subplots()
    288         self._make_plot()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    451         # no non-numeric frames or series allowed
    452         if is_empty:
--> 453             raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
    454 
    455         self.data = numeric_data.apply(self._convert_to_ndarray)
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Please, what is your version of Pandas?

Comment: According to `print(pd.__version__)`, it is 1.3.3.

Comment: The plot below is not what you expect?

Comment: Yes, I want to see that, but still get the same error. I have updated the post with full error report.

Comment: Try `row.astype(int).plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: @Corralien: Right. That works. Thank you. Please add that to the answer. Maybe there are some issues with version changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Based on your post edit, it seems your are data are not numeric

```
Metric Value    512
Metric Value    512
Metric Value    512
Metric Value    512
Name: 4, dtype: object  # <- NOT NUMERIC
```

Try to convert your row (or your dataframe) as numeric:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Metric Value    object
Metric Value    object
Metric Value    object
Metric Value    object
dtype: object

>>> df = df.astype(float)  # convert whole dataframe to float

>>> df.dtypes
Metric Value    float64
Metric Value    float64
Metric Value    float64
Metric Value    float64
dtype: object
```

---

Your code seems to work even if all columns have the same name:

```
row = df.iloc[4]
row.plot(kind='bar')  # TypeError: no numeric data to plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I thought maybe it is trying to put column names (not values) in the plot. So, indeed "Metric Value" can not be used as y-axis.

Comment: How can I convert the `row` to a plain array, e.g. [512 512 512 512]?

Comment: `row.to_numpy()` or `row.values`

Comment: If I use `plt.plot(row.values)`, I can see a line chart. I will then have to work with matplotlib to convert it to bar chart. I was intended to use `pandas.plot()`.

Comment: @mahmood. I updated my answer to fix the dtype bug.

Comment: Regarding the conversion of whole dataframe, as you can see in the example, the 5th row is float. So, is `df.astype(int)` a good solution then? This is a not a big problem now, because I can manually specify `row.astype(float)` where I want. Is there any way to auto convert the fields from object to int or float?